# Run Spring Batch Job programmatically?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch application, which I start with the `CommandLineJobRunner`. But now I have to embed this application into our corporate environment. There we have an own Launcher application which I have to use. For this launcher application I need a startup class with a main method which will be called at startup and where I would have to launch Spring Batch.

Is the only way to manually assign a `JobLauncher` and run the Job with this launcher or is there a class in Spring Batch which would support that (or do someone know a sample)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can launch your job programmatically. If you see [in the source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/CommandLineJobRunner.java.html) of `CommandLineJobRunner`, the main method just create a Spring context and use the launcher to run the job. So you can do this in your new application.

Answer (score 16):

Using a Spring Boot Application if you don't want to use the CommandLineRunner (for some reason or if you need some custom logic), you can always do something like :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(YourApplication.class);
    app.setWebEnvironment(false);
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = app.run(args);

    JobLauncher jobLauncher = ctx.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
    Job job = ctx.getBean("your-job-here", Job.class);
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().toJobParameters();


    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
    BatchStatus batchStatus = jobExecution.getStatus();
}
```

Comment: I tried with this approach, but somehow context could not find bean of "your-job-here" despite of the fact I can see that bean was initialised by Spring container :(. Any idea why?

Comment: It work for me well. I made on change to stop default execution of Job. Added line in application.properties :-   spring.batch.job.enabled=false

Answer (score 6):

JobLauncher can be used to invoke the Job programatically. JobLauncher can be autowired in your Servlet/Controller if you're looking for a way to trigger jobs from a webapp:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/htmlsingle/#runningJobsFromWebContainer