# Firing Quartz jobs manually

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

We have several Quartz jobs configured in our application. During development, we leave the quartz scheduler in standby - however, we sometimes want to start a job manually (for development purposes). If I call fireTrigger, it tells me I need to start the scheduler. However, if I start the scheduler, it will also immediately schedule all the other jobs, which is not what I want (since they may trigger while I'm debugging the manually fired job).

I could pause all triggers when I start the scheduler, but then I have to deal with misfire instructions etc.

Is there a simple way to fire off a job manually without having to deal with pausing and misfires (i.e. a fireTrigger which works even if the scheduler is in standby)?

Answer (score 26):

this is the loop you will require to fire the job manually:

```
SchedulerFactory stdSchedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler scheduler = stdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler();

// loop jobs by group
for (String groupName : scheduler.getJobGroupNames()) {
    // get jobkey
    for (JobKey jobKey : scheduler.getJobKeys(GroupMatcher.jobGroupEquals(groupName))) {
        String jobName = jobKey.getName();
        String jobGroup = jobKey.getGroup();
        scheduler.triggerJob(jobName, jobGroup);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work anymore on 2.2.1 as triggerJob() takes JobKey as parameter. [See doc](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#triggerJob(org.quartz.JobKey)) 
Use @Minarul-Haque respsonse instead

Answer (score 10):

All the Jobs registered in the Quartz Scheduler are uniquely identified by the JobKey which is composed of a name and group . You can fire the job which has a given JobKey immediately by calling `triggerJob(JobKey jobKey)` of your Scheduler instance.

```
// Create a new Job 
JobKey jobKey = JobKey.jobKey("myNewJob", "myJobGroup");
JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(MyJob.class).withIdentity(jobKey).storeDurably().build();

// Register this job to the scheduler
scheduler.addJob(job, true);

// Immediately fire the Job MyJob.class
scheduler.triggerJob(jobKey);
```

**Note:**

scheduler is the Scheduler instance used throughout your application . Its start() method should be already called after it is created.

The job is the durable job which cannot attach any triggers or cron to it .It can only be fired programmatically by calling `triggerJob(JobKey jobKey)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a trigger filter in your scheduler

```
this.scheduler.addGlobalTriggerListener(new DebugExecutionFilter());
```

The debug execution filter will add a veto when the execution is not volatile (not scheduled to run  immediately) and you are in debug mode .

Here is an implementation example :

```
private static class DebugExecutionFilter implements TriggerListener
{

    public DebugExecutionFilter()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return "Task execution filter";
    }

    @Override
    public void triggerFired(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.quartz.TriggerListener#vetoJobExecution(org.quartz.Trigger, org.quartz.JobExecutionContext) */
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    /**
     * A veto is added if :
     *  - For non volatile trigger if we are in debug mode
     */
    public boolean vetoJobExecution(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context)
    {

        try
        {
            // 
            if ( !trigger.isVolatile() && isDebugMode() )
            {
                return true;
            }

            //task is run by scheduler.triggerJobWithVolatileTrigger() for immediate schedule
            //or task is schedule and we are not in debugMode
            return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void triggerMisfired(Trigger trigger)
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void triggerComplete(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context, int triggerInstructionCode)
    {
        // do nothing
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mmounirou! Maybe I didn't describe the issue exactly, but I actually do want non-paused triggers to be fired in development mode. Its just that in development mode, the schedulers are left in standby and all triggers are paused by default. If I now go to our scheduled jobs page and start one of the schedulers with the intention of running one of the jobs manually (beside each job, we have a "run now" button), all the other jobs start misfiring. I basically want paused jobs to do nothing on misfire in development mode - is there maybe a global way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No need for `start-time` and `end-time`.

```xml
<trigger>
    <cron>
        <name>TestTrigger</name>
        <group>CronSampleTrigger</group>
        <description>CronSampleTrigger</description>
        <job-name>TestJob</job-name>
        <job-group>jobGroup1</job-group>

        <!--<start-time>1982-06-28T18:15:00.0Z</start-time>
        <end-time>2020-05-04T18:13:51.0Z</end-time>-->

        <cron-expression>0 0/1 * * * ?</cron-expression>
    </cron>
</trigger>
```