# Is there any way to get job keys in Quartz by job name

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Right now I'm searching for functionality to get job keys by job name in Quartz library.

I see that `Scheduler` has method to get job keys by group name using `GroupMatcher<JobKey>` also `Quartz` has `NameMatcher` which can be user in same way as `GroupMatcher`

```
Set<JobKey> getJobKeys(NameMatcher<JobKey> matcher) throws SchedulerException;
```

Do you know is this functionality already exists in Quartz library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An API for getting the `JobKey` by job's name using a `NameMatcher` does not exist AFAIK.

However, it's actually easy to get a job's key from its name just by iterating the keys:

```
public JobKey findJobKey(String jobName) {
    // Check running jobs first
    for (JobExecutionContext runningJob : scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs()) {
        if (Objects.equals(jobName, runningJob.getJobDetail().getKey().getName())) {
            return runningJob.getJobDetail().getKey();
        }
    }
    // Check all jobs if not found
    for (String groupName : scheduler.getJobGroupNames()) {
        for (JobKey jobKey : scheduler.getJobKeys(GroupMatcher.jobGroupEquals(groupName))) {
            if (Objects.equals(jobName, jobKey.getName())) {
                return jobKey;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could skip the scheduler.getJobGroupNames() loop by using GroupMatcher.anyGroup() since you're looping through all of them anyway.